# Phonegap on Android: AJAX request fails when setting Accept: 'application/xml' on request header

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am making GET requests to the Assembla REST API. You can read about it here: http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Assembla_REST_API

The API requires you to set Accept: 'application/xml' on the request header to receive xml data back. Otherwise, html comes back in the response.

My service calls work in iOS and in Safari, but do not return anything in Android.

My cordova.xml file has `<access origin=".*"/>` so I do not think it is a whitelist issue. I have tried just about every variation I could think of here.

Sample ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.assembla.com/spaces/my_spaces',
    username: userModel.get('username'),
    password: userModel.get('password'),
    headers: { 
        Accept: 'application/xml'
    },
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});
```

Like I said, this request will not hit either onSuccess or onError in Android. The request works perfectly fine in iOS and in Safari. If I take out the headers property, the request will hit onSuccess in Android but will return html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the request and response in firebug or httpheaders to see if they look correct? Basically look to see that your header is set correctly on the request. Double check you aren't getting any server errors, and see if the response coming back is actually xml.

Comment: So it looks like the Authorization header is getting excluded from the Android request even though username and password are set.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization was failing on Android with just setting the username and password properties on the ajax request. Manually setting the headers fixed the issue.

```
headers: { 
    Accept: 'application/xml',
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa('username:password')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem here : [Soap query with jQuery / Phonegap always fail on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176985/soap-query-with-jquery-phonegap-always-fail-on-android) whereas I don't need to specify any authorization parameters.